# Python 3.3 functions on pairs in a list

Tags: list, python-3.x

I am trying to create a program that will find the difference between all pairs in a list. For example
[2,4,6]
Would then make a list containing the difference
[2,2]
Is there a way to do this

Comment: Yes, there certainly *is* a way to do this. What have you tried?

Comment: If you want to avoid being down voted, you need to provide the code you have tried so far, even if it isn't working.

Answer (score 3):

[Itertools Recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes): `pairwise`

```
from itertools import tee

def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)

def diffs(iterable):
    return [b - a for a, b in pairwise(iterable)]

print(diffs([2,4,6]))
```

Answer (score 2):

`[L[i+1] - L[i] for i in range(len(L)-1)]` will do it.

Some other ways also using a list comprehension:

`[L[i+1] - L[i] for i in range(len(L[:-1]))]`

`[L[i] - L[i-1] for i in range(1, len(L[1:]))]`

Using `map`:

`list(map(lambda i: L[i+1]-L[i], range(len(L[:-1]))))`

`list(map(lambda i: L[i]-L[i-1], range(1, len(L[1:]))))`

Using `map` and the `operator` module:

`list(map(operator.sub, L[1:], L[:-1]))`

Using `zip` (this one is probably the nicest way, imo):

`[x - y for x, y in zip(L[1:], L[:-1])]`

A more verbose approach if you aren't familiar with list comprehensions or with `map` (GET FAMILIAR!):

```
def differences(L1,L2):
    L = []
    for V1,V2 in zip(L1,L2):
        L.append(V2-V1)
    return L

diffs = differences(L[:-1],L[1:])
```

And a similar, but much better way to do it using a generator:

```
def differences(L1,L2):
    for V1,V2 in zip(L1,L2):
        yield V2-V1

diffs = list(differences(L[:-1],L[1:]))
```

And here is the generator comprehension equivalent of the above generator(notice it's almost exactly the same as the last list comprehension above, except it uses the list function instead of brackets):

```
list(V2-V1 for V1,V2 in zip(L[:-1],L[1:]))
```

Study all of these ways of doing it very closely and you will learn a lot of Python.

Comment: I think you mean `[L[i] - L[i-1] for i in range(1, len(L))]`